# Como alterar (substituir) a informação de dentro de um arquivo .txt usando .bat?

Tags: batch

O que eu quero fazer é tipo um sed em shell.

Tenho um arquivo `.txt` como varias informações dentro, quero substituir uma sequencia de números por outra.

Até onde fiz o script identifica o arquivos através de uma variável `SET /P COD01=Cod_01`: e copia para outra pasta.

Criei outra variável `SET /P COD02=Cod_0:`: que recebo a informação de deve substituir a COD01.

Agora não sei como faço o retante.

Comment: Bem vinda ao Stack Overflow, Maressa! Por favor [edite sua pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/209280/edit) e explique melhor o que você está tentando fazer - quantos arquivos você pretende modificar? É apenas uma linha de texto dentro de cada um deles ou mais? Inclua também o código que você já fez. E aproveite e [faça o tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para conhecer melhor o site! :)

Answer (score 0):

A algum tempo atrás precisei trocar uma sigla dentro de um arquivo em varios servidores diferentes, então pesquisando encontrei a solução abaixo.

Utiliza o [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) para encontrar a sequencia e substituir, utilizei o seu exemplo de variável e alterei o código, além disso faz um backup.

```
@echo off    
@SET /P COD01=Cod_01
@SET /P COD02=Cod_02

@call:DoReplace %COD01% %COD02% arquivooriginal.txt arquivomodificado.txt
@exit /b

::Cria o arquivo do PowerShell para ser executado conforme parâmetros acima.
:DoReplace
@echo ^(Get-Content "%3"^) ^| ForEach-Object { $_ -replace %1, %2 } ^| Set-Content %4>Rep.ps1
::Executa o arquivo criado.
@Powershell.exe -executionpolicy ByPass -File Rep.ps1
::Deleta o arquivo.
@if exist Rep.ps1 del Rep.ps1
:: Renomeia.
@RENAME arquivooriginal.txt arquivooriginal_old.txt
@RENAME arquivomodificado.txt arquivooriginal.txt
```